# upgrade AjaxControlToolkit to version 15 get an error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Recently I update the AjaxControlToolkit from version 3.5 to 15.1 and upgrade the .net framework form 2.1 to 4.6. After update AjaxControlToolkit, I got the error.

There is the error:

```
   Extender control 'deleteMsg' cannot extend 'deleteConfirm'. Extender controls of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.DynamicPopulateExtender' cannot extend controls of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.
```

there is the code for control.

```
<div id="deleteConfirm" runat="server">
<asp:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="deleteMsg" TargetControlID="deleteConfirm"
                            PopulateTriggerControlID="deleteButton" runat="server" CustomScript='<%# String.Format("populateDynamic(""{0}"", ""{1}"")", Eval("Title"), Eval("AnnouncementDate")) %>'>
                        </asp:DynamicPopulateExtender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in ACT 15.1 DynamicPopulateExtender TargetControlType attribute was changed to WebControl instead of Control. This, particularly, means you can no longer attach it to div.

You can try to replace div with asp:Panel as illustrated at [Sample site DynamicPopulate page](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/DynamicPopulate/DynamicPopulate.aspx).